# Type casting with type in variable

Tags: swift, swift3, casting

Is it possible to cast an object to a type which is stored in a member variable?

I've tried this:

```
let targetClass = type(of: MyTargetClass)
...

if anyObject is targetClass { // ERROR: use of undeclared type 'targetClass'
let test = anyObject as! targetClass // ERROR: use of undeclared type 'targetClass'
}
```

But it doesn't work because it says "use of undeclared type 'targetClass'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The type cast is a compile time thing. It lets the compiler know what methods are available and how to do the linking.

You can use [`Mirror`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror) to gather information about your object at runtime, but it looks like invoking methods dynamically can still only be done on classes derived from `NSObject`.